# chef: knife deps - how to specify a cookbook version

Tags: chef, knife

RE: https://docs.chef.io/knife_deps.html

With the **knife deps --remote** option, I can query our chef server. **knife cookbook list -a** will return all the cookbook versions. How can I use **knife deps** to query the dependencies of a particular version of a cookbook? I tried all sorts of delimiters to append the version number to the cookbook name and I have tried them as separate arguments. Tried to dig into the ruby code and found that is difficult to do - the purpose and organization of all those gems is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer currently exists. Trying to take my bounty back!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a must to use "knife deps"? because you can achieve your goal by using the "knife search" command, like so:

```
knife search -i 'cookbooks:your-cookbook' -a cookbooks.your-cookbook.version
```

This will give you output that shows the hostname and the cookbook version:

```
1 items found

server.name.example:
  cookbooks.cs-redis.version: 0.3.2
```

Another thing you can do is to use a base cookbook and set an attribute on the node with the cookbook versions.

Example:

```
run_context.cookbook_collection.each do |key, cookbook|
  node.set['base_cookbook']['cookbook_versions'][cookbook.name] = cookbook.version
end
```

Then you can query the versions used by a node like so:

```
knife node show <node-name> -a base_cookbook.cookbook_versions
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am probably more concerned about cookbooks dependent upon other cookbooks, but you give a way to find nodes dependent upon cookbooks.